# Does it make sense to do backpropagation every n iteration in parts of a neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I have a neural network that branches at some point to two sub-networks.

When I train the sub-networks separately, I get fairly good accuracy. However, when I train them both, it seems that one of the tasks is hijacking the weights in the common layer hence creating a situation where I have one task with really good accuracy and the other with poor accuracy.

To reduce the impact of the more powerful task, I was thinking of allowing weight updates every n iteration with n to be defined.

Do you think that makes sense ?

Comment: Why not just make two networks if you have two different tasks?

Comment: @Dzjkb The two tasks are strongly related. Initially, I had two separate networks. I want to experiment the joint architecture.

Comment: You could try this approach then https://deepmind.com/blog/enabling-continual-learning-in-neural-networks/

Comment: @Dzjkb this is a really interesting paper. I will definitely investigate this approach. For now, I would like to investigate the architecture I have. I would like to know whether it makes sense mathematically to do backpropagation every n iteration for the more powerful task i.e the task that is "hijacking" the learning process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have more data for one task than the other? that could explain why the task with more data is weighted as more important - if there's more data that needs fitting.

if that is the case then try to balance the data.
either way, I would try to play with the loss function rather than with the num of updates. just make the second task worth more when you define the loss function..

a hacky way of doing that would be to over-sample the data from the task that isn't doing as well. so get the network to read the same data a few times before moving to the other task, thus making it more important for the network to fit.

also, I would play with the timing of switching between tasks. if you have a lot of data on both tasks then when you train on task A the network will learn how to do it well, then when you train on task B for a long time the network will change weights and "forgot" when it learned on task A, as those weights don't help in solving task B. even if you iterate both tasks a few times, the task the network finishes training on will end up being "worth more". so make sure you mix between tasks on every epoch (ideally, randomly sample every batch from either tasks)

Comment: Thanks. The order of magnitude of losses in the tasks I am dealing with is different. For example, in the least powerful task, I have values around 2.1 whereas in the most powerful task, I have values around 0.1. Does it make more sense to give more weight to the task with smaller loss values or smaller weight to the one with bigger loss?

Comment: well it depends on what you want to accomplish. but if you want the network to be equally good on both tasks then give more weight to the one with the bigger loss. this will make the network "want" to solve it better, and reduce the loss. but obviously, this might cause an increase in the loss of other problems the network is solving...